# Is it possible to access audit data from a bi-temporal table in Timescale

Tags: timescaledb

In the [Why Use TimescaleDB over Relational DBs?](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/introduction/timescaledb-vs-postgres) article the following example is given for a bi-temporal use case

```sql
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 day', time) AS day,
    asset_code,
    last(price, time_recorded)
FROM prices
WHERE time > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY day, asset_code
ORDER BY day DESC, asset_code;
```

If we assume that the `prices` table contains an recorded_by column is it possible to write a query that returns both a time_recorded and recorded_by column?

For example given the following input:

```
+------------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
|       time       | asset_code | price |  time_recorded   | recorded_by |
+------------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
| 2019-08-08 12:00 |          1 | 9     | 2019-08-08 12:00 | foo         |
| 2019-08-09 15:30 |          1 | 10    | 2019-08-09 15:30 | foo         |
| 2019-08-08 12:00 |          1 | 9.5   | 2019-08-09 15:00 | bar         |
+------------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
```

You would expect the following output:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
|    day     | asset_code | price |  time_recorded   | recorded_by |
+------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
| 2019-08-09 |          1 | 10    | 2019-08-09 15:30 | foo         |
| 2019-08-08 |          1 | 9.5   | 2019-08-09 13:00 | bar         |
+------------+------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can actually have both arguments of the last function refer to the same column, e.g.

```sql
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 day', time) AS day,
    asset_code,
    last(price, time_recorded) AS price,
    last(time_recorded, time_recorded) AS time_recorded,
    last(recorded_by, time_recorded) AS recorded_by
FROM prices
WHERE time > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY day, asset_code
ORDER BY day DESC, asset_code;
```